# How to add number to circle

Tags: javascript, svg, jsfiddle

I have used jsFiddle to create a number of circles with predefined locations.
How can I add numbers on theses circles, so that each circle has a number ?

[jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/sarmadm/aancdsc4/)

```
function draw_circle(center_x, center_y){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var centerX = center_x;
    var centerY = center_y;
    var radius = 30
    ;

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'lightblue';
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth =3;
    context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
    context.stroke();
  }
```

Comment: If you've created a JS Fiddle which demonstrates your problem it might be worth adding the link to that, so that we can see the code in action and edit/update without having to first create our own reproduction. The less minimising the friction tends to get better answers more quickly. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simplified version of your sample showing how to number the circles

The textnode is appended right after the circle. The opacity of the circle is set to 0.5, otherwise the text is covered by the circle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type = "text/javascript" 
         src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
    <style>
     svg .circle {
         stroke: yellow;
         opacity: 0.5;
         stroke-width: 2;
     }
     </style> 
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var width = 900, height = 650;
    var radius = 30; 
    var numCircles = 10;
    var circles=[[133,396],[234,511.0000305175781],[369,116],[348,388],[231,278],[351,232],[520,228],[116,199],[522,425],[229,120]];
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height).attr("id", 'svg');
    var g_circles = svg.append("g").attr("class", "circles");
    $.each(circles, function(i, d) {
        g_circles.append("circle").attr("class", "circle").attr("id", "circle" + i).attr("r", radius).attr("cx", d[0]).attr("cy", d[1]);
        g_circles.append("text").attr("x", d[0]-5).attr("y", d[1]+5).text(i);
    });
});
      </script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: are the numbers  generated randomly ? can I add character for some circles and number for others ?

Comment: no, they are represented by `.text(i)` which is the order in which you build your array of circles but you could put everything you like instead of the i